# URL rewriting in asp.net for content management system

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

URL rewriting in asp.net for content management system

Comment: Did you mean: "URL rewriting in asp.net for content management system?"

Comment: Dear Sir
i want to implement in content management system .

Answer (score 0):

[Url Rewriting with ASP.NET by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

[URL Rewriting in ASP.NET by Scott Mitchell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've done old-school URL Rewriting in ASP.NET and it works, but I'd really recommend that you look into using Routing instead. It works with ASP.NET Webforms as well as MVC, and it's more smoothly baked into the ASP.NET system.

One other option you can look into is the IIS URL Rewriting module. It's worked well for me.